# Trimming lists using a loop

Tags: python, list

I have few lists like:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [4, 6, 5, 9, 2]
c = [4, 7, 9, 1, 2]
```

I want to trim all of them using a loop, instead of doing as below:

```
a[-2:]
b[-2:]
c[-2:]
```

I tried but got confused with pass by value or pass by reference fundamentals, looked into other questions as well but no help.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for l in [a, b, c]:
    del l[-2:]
```

This removes the last two elements from each list. If you want to remove all but the last two elements only, do this:

```
for l in [a, b, c]:
    del l[:-2]
```

There's no need to worry about references here; the list over which the for loop iterates contains references to `a`, `b` and `c`, and each list is mutated in-place by deleting a list slice.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [a, b, c]
x = map(lambda lst: lst[-2:], x)
```

Comment: In Python 3.x, this would store an iterator in `x` instead of another list (`map` in Python 3.x returns iterators).

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the unwanted items from the existing lists, using a loop:

```
for list in [a, b, c]:
   del a[:-2]
```

Or, creating new lists containing only the correct items, using a list comprehension:

```
(a, b, c) = [x[-2:] for x in (a, b, c)]
```